# How to export the translation of a vocabulary?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, taxonomy-terms

I have 2 vocabularies. `Vocabulary 1` and `Vocabulary 2`.

`Vocabulary 1` is exported in feature `test_feature1` and `Vocabulary 2` is exported in `test_feature2`.

My site is multilingual. I want to export the translation of `Vocabulary 1` in `test_feature1` and the translation of `Vocabulary 2` in `test_feature2`.

How will I do that?

I have tried [Features Translations](https://www.drupal.org/project/features_translations) but it exports a set of translations like translations of all the taxonomies.

Is there any other method to export the translations of a specific vocabulary in a module. Any other hook? which I can implement in both modules for each vocabulary?

Comment: `like translations of all the taxonomies` well, an option could be to edit the module generated by features and remove the stuff that you don't want.

Comment: This will create conflicts between two features.